Link/append Item from Asset Browser using python
I’m working with a giant asset library containing thousands of products with product IDs in their names.
I’d like to have an option to automatically batch import a bunch of assets into my scene. To reduce complexity for now, let’s say the full names of the assets I want are saved in a list.
I know that the Asset Browser is somewhat limited in terms of its Python accessibility, but is something like this possible?
I tried a method that went through all prefs.filepaths.asset_libraries and searched for the assets, but this was far too slow.

Hello, yeah batch-importing assets is not possible in vanilla AFAIK. I don't think the devs built the asset system with humongous libraries in mind. It's on the todo list of my batch asset browser addon for a long time. :) I'll see what i can do. Cheers
